# Remove delay after first symbol on key hold

Tags: python-3.x, input, ubuntu-14.04, curses, python-curses

When I press and hold a key, a first symbol is typed, then there is a little delay, and then other symbols are typed fast. Something like this:

[image]

Same happens in Terminal. Same happens in linux console (tty), even though this delay is smaller there.

I'm working on a console app in Python that uses `curses`, and it processes the presses of arrow keys and this delay is present there as well.

I want to get rid of this delay, so that when I press and hold a key - it would send signals with uniformly, without any specific delays after first (or whichever) symbol.

How can I do it? Should I use something from the arsenal of `curses`? Or tinker with some system-wide settings?

EDIT1: I think I've found one way. I can go to keyboard settings and set delay of autorepeat. But it changes it globally and only for my graphical interface. It doesn't change anything in linux console. So, I'm looking fo a way to do it in console as well, and also so it would affect only my app, not the whole system.

and a way for linux console: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58651/adjusting-keyboard-sensitivity-in-a-command-line-terminal

but still looking for an app-only way.

Comment: Haven't tried, but maybe checkout `curses.cbreak` and `curses.raw` and see if that has some effect.

Comment: Some system-specific ioctl might do this, but curses (which uses termios) won't do what OP is asking, as stated.

Comment: Check your keyboard settings, there is a repeat character delay as well as repeat char rate setting for most keyboards.